# Using SNAP in an automated pipeline

Tags: python, sentinel-2, sentinel-1, sentinel-snap

I found a way to extract data from Copernicus SciHub, but I'd love to find a way to automate to pre-processing in a Python script for both S2 and S1 data without having to use SNAP Desktop. Is there any way to use the algorithms like `sen2cor` so I can have a resulting geoTIFF?

Answer (score 2):

There's a python library for SNAP `snappy`. As far as I know, it is not yet supported in `python 3+`.

You can either install python 2.7 and configure SNAP, or a better way is to create [anaconda](https://www.google.com/search?channel=trow2&client=firefox-b-d&q=anaconda) virtual environment with `python 2.7`. [This post](https://thegeoict.com/blog/2019/08/21/setup-development-environment-for-snap/) explains how to do it.